# The first three max value in a column in python

Tags: python, pandas

I am new in Python. I would like to know how should I extract the first three value of a column in Python. I used CSV file. Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
census_df = pd.read_csv('census.csv')

def answer_five():

    return census_df['COUNTY'].idxmax(3)

answer_five()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you want either

```
# get first three
census_df['COUNTY'].head(3)
```

or

```
# get largest three
census_df['COUNTY'].nlargest(3)
```

if you want the records with the 3 largest `COUNTY` values

```
census_df.iloc[census_df['COUNTY'].argsort()[-3:]]
```

Comment: This code gave the index of records. Is there any way that I see the complete record or special column of it?