# Pandas function operations

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-datareader

Data is from the United States Census Bureau. Counties are political and geographic subdivisions of states in the United States. This dataset contains population data for counties and states in the US from 2010 to 2015.

Which state has the most counties in it? (hint: consider the sumlevel key carefully! You'll need this for future questions too...)

I can not fetch the county name out of the code. Please help

my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
census_df = pd.read_csv('census.csv')
census_df.head()
def answer_five():
    return census_df.groupby('STNAME').COUNTY.sum().max()



answer_five()
```

Comment: This question does not include any sample data or any attempt at filtering the data, additionally this question looks like homework so you'll need to show more efforts here

Comment: Did you just copy your homework excercise?

Comment: It seems answer is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40957458/2901002)

Comment: Can confirm this is an assignment question.

Comment: Posting Courserva assignments is a violation of Coursera Honor Code. Don't do this

Answer (score 2):

Here is the answer that worked for me:

```
def answer_five():
    return census_df.groupby(["STNAME"],sort=False).sum()["COUNTY"].idxmax()
```

First part created aggregated df

```
census_df.groupby(["STNAME"],sort=False).sum()
```

Second part takes the col you need

```
["COUNTY"].idxmax()
```

and returns value corresponding to index with max, check [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html)

Comment: This looks wrong to me.  COUNTY, according to the [co-est2015-alldata.pdf][1], is the FIPS code which is a variable int.  Based on the code and explanation I believe you are summing these ints that can be >= 1, it is not a 1-to-1 relationship.  What should happen here is some soft of +=1 if SUMLEV = 50.


  [1]: https://www2.census.gov/programs-surveys/popest/technical-documentation/file-layouts/2010-2015/co-est2015-alldata.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Just a correction to your entire code.

First, according to the source, `SUMLEV` of 50 means the row is a county. Two ways to answer this.

Thought process (think of it like in Excel):
You want to count the number of "county rows" in each state group.
First, you create the mask/condition to select all `SUMLEV == 50` ("county rows").
Then group them by `STNAME`.
Then use `.size()` to count the number of rows in each grouping.

```
# this is it!
def answer_five():
    mask = (census_df.SUMLEV == 50)
    max_index = census_df[mask].groupby('STNAME').size().idxmax()
    return max_index

# not so elegant
def answer_five():
    census_df['Counts'] = 1
    mask = (census_df.SUMLEV == 50)
    max_index = census_df[mask].groupby('STNAME')['Counts'].sum().idxmax()
    return max_index
```

You are welcome. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html

Answer (score 2):

Actually you can just count the number in states level instead of looking into County details.

And this should work:

```
census_df[census_df['SUMLEV']==50].groupby(['STNAME']).size().idxmax()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def answer_five():
    new_df = census_df[census_df['SUMLEV'] == 50]
    x = new_df.groupby('STNAME')
    return x.count()['COUNTY'].idxmax()


answer_five()
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

It's the change from `.max()` to `idxmax()` that returns the correct value for the `STNAME` rather than a large integer.

Answer (score 0):

We can also do this question using `sum()` function

```
def answer_five():
  return census_df.groupby(["STNAME"]).sum()["COUNTY"].idxmax()
```

Using `sum()` it will sum up all the values in COUNTY column from which we can apply `idxmax()` to find the the state which has the highest no:of counties.

Answer (score 0):

```
def answer_five():
    county = census_df[census_df['SUMLEV']==50]
    county = county.groupby(['STNAME']).count()

    return county['SUMLEV'].idxmax(axis=0)

answer_five()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
def answer_five():
    df=census_df.groupby(['STNAME'])
    df=df.sum();
    fd=df['COUNTY'].max()
    df=df[df['COUNTY']==fd]
    return df.index[0]
answer_five()
```

Comment: Simple and easy

Answer (score -1):

```
def answer_five():
    return census_df.groupby('STNAME')['CTYNAME'].count().idxmax()
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.